# DRF Endpoint Unexpectedly Deleting Related Objects

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following function used to update an object's `status` value using a `ModelViewSet` in Django Rest Framework.

```
class TaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    filterset_fields = ['status', 'project', 'is_goal', 'routine']

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['updated_at'] = timezone.now()

        self._handle_status_update(request)

        print(request.data)

        print(self.get_object().children.all())
        response = super().partial_update(request)
        print(self.get_object().children.all())

    return response
```

The relation is self referential (set through `Task.parent`) with a reverse reference of children:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

For some reason, executing this results in all of the object's children relations being dropped. The `parent` values of all related objects are being saved as `null`. The first print expression (before the `partial_update`) generates a list of related children, whereas the expression immediately following it produces an empty queryset.

The `request.data` does not show anything unusual:

```
{'id': 251, 'status': 1, 'partial': True, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 23, 16, 23, 2, 665627, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
```

I am not running any signals, nor am I overriding `save()` in the model or the serializer or anywhere else. What caveat could I be missing here?

EDIT:
This is how I am instantiating the `children` field in the serializer.

```
children = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, required=False, default=[], queryset=Task.objects.all())
```

I am wondering if setting the default to `[]` is causing this behavior (even though I am setting partial to true in the request).

Comment: Can you share the serializer?

Comment: Yes, I found the answer there. I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my update, changing the field to read only in my serializer seemed to resolve it:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    children = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True, required=False, default=[])
    ...
```